# Is running spark on kubernetes still experimental?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

We would like to test some `Spark` submission on a `Kubernetes` cluster;

However, the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/running-on-kubernetes.html) is kind of ambiguous.

> Spark can run on clusters managed by Kubernetes. This feature makes use of native Kubernetes scheduler that has been added to Spark.
>
> **The Kubernetes scheduler is currently experimental. In future versions, there may be behavioral changes around configuration, container images and entrypoints.**

Does this mean that the `kubernetes` scheduler itself is experimental or some kind of its implementation related to spark?

Does it make sense to run spark on `Kubernetes` in production-grade environments?

Comment: This means that *using kubernetes scheduler inside of spark* is experimental. And yes it is still experimental. Another way to tell you : "Use it as your own risks!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it's experimental if you are using the Spark Kubernetes scheduler like you mentioned [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/running-on-kubernetes.html). Use it at your own risk.
2. Not really, if you are running a standalone cluster in Kubernetes without the Kubernetes scheduler. This means create a master in a Kubernetes pod and then allocate a number of slave pods that talk to that master. Then submitting your jobs with the good old `spark-summit` without `--master k8s://` command and with the usual `--master spark://` command. The downside of this basically that your Spark cluster in Kubernetes is static.